# Django Testing Using AsyncClient and Authentication

Tags: django, django-testing, pytest-django, pytest-asyncio

I have a basic [Asynchronous Class Based View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/#asynchronous-class-based-views):

```py
class AsyncAuthenticationView(View):
    async def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        authenticated: bool = await sync_to_async(lambda: request.user.is_authenticated)()
        if not authenticated:
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)

        return HttpResponse('Success', status=200)
```

And two simple tests:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def authenticated_async_client(user) -> AsyncClient:
    client = AsyncClient()
    client.force_login(user)
    return client

class TestAsyncAuthenticationView:
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_with_async_client(self, authenticated_async_client: AsyncClient):
        """This test fails, with response code 401 instead of 200"""
        response = await authenticated_async_client.post(
            reverse('auth-test'),
            'abc',
            content_type="text/html",
        )
        assert 200 == response.status_code  # fails with 401

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_with_async_request_factory(self, async_rf: AsyncRequestFactory, user):
        """This test succeeds correctly with response code 200"""
        r = async_rf.post('/fake-url', 'abc', content_type='text/html')
        r.user = user
        r.session = {}
        response = await AsyncAuthenticationView().post(r)
        assert 200 == response.status_code
```

The first test which uses the `AsyncClient` always fails to authenticate returning status code `401` while the second test is passing just fine with status code `200`.

Based on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#testing-asynchronous-code) the `AsyncClient` has all the same methods, so I am not not why the test is failing. Perhaps there is a different authentication method that needs to be used?

The `AsyncRequestFactory` that is being used in the second test is from the [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#async-rf-asyncrequestfactory) package.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.